# incompatible types when assigning to type

Tags: c

I am trying to create a Table and the entries of the table are of a structure type.
I am getting an error "incompatible types when assigning to type 'SortTableRows' from type 'TableRow' ".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct TableRow
{
    int  startingValue;
    int entries[100];
}TableRow;

typedef TableRow SortTableRows[20]; //Table Containing entries of type TableRow

SortTableRows* SortTableRowsPtr;

int main()
{

    TableRow *tableRow;
    tableRow = malloc(sizeof(TableRow));
    tableRow = NULL;
    SortTableRowsPtr[2]=*tableRow; //Error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `tableRow = malloc(sizeof(TableRow)); tableRow = NULL;` You just leaked memory in the second-fewest lines possible (only a blind unassigned `malloc()` could do it faster).

Comment: Remove typedef for `typedef TableRow SortTableRows[20];` you not need typedef here to declare array of struct. just do `TableRow SortTableRows[20];`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan not to mention that that typedef is wrong

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean to use `(*SortTableRowsPtr)[2]`, i.e. assigning to the third array entry of type `TableRow` in the `SortTableRows` array.

Or should `SortTableRowsPtr` be an array of 20 pointers to `TableRow`?

```
typedef TableRow (*SortTableRows)[20];
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following? Where by you assign the tableRow to the 3rd row in your SortTableRows array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct TableRow
{
    int  startingValue;
    int entries[100];
}TableRow_t;

int main()
{

    TableRow_t SortTableRows[20];
    TableRow_t *tableRow = NULL;

    /* Put some data into the 3rd row */
    SortTableRows[2].startingValue = 2;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            SortTableRows[2].entries[i] = i;
    }

    tableRow = &(SortTableRows[2]);

    printf("%d: %d, %d, %d\n", 
                    tableRow->startingValue,
                    tableRow->entries[0],
                    tableRow->entries[1],
                    tableRow->entries[2]);

    return 0;
}
```